# How can I convert WebM file to WebP file with transparency?

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, webp

I tried it with ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg input.webm output.webp
```

`input.webm` contains transparent background and But the alpha channel becomes white in webp. I think that means alpha channel doesn't come together.

I extracted frames with [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345064/unable-to-extract-frames-in-webp-from-webm-video):

```
ffmpeg -i input.xxx -c:v libwebp output_%03d.webp
```

And it also gives me webp files with white background.

How can I convert it properly with alpha channel? OR should I convert it from other format(extension)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `-c:v libvpx` option **before** the input to change the decoder like in this example for the first frame (`-frames:v 1`):

```bash
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx -i input.webm -frames:v 1 -c:v libwebp -y output.webp
```

[This comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/fgpyfb/help_with_webm_with_alpha_channel/fk6esxp/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) says that:

> FFmpeg's native VPx decoders don't decode alpha. You have to use the libvpx decoder

You can check your decoders using `ffmpeg -decoders | grep libvpx` and you should see an output like this:

```
 V....D libvpx               libvpx VP8 (codec vp8)
 V....D libvpx-vp9           libvpx VP9 (codec vp9)
```

According to that output, `libvpx` would be the decoder for VP8 and `libvpx-vp9` for VP9.

You can check the codec of your video using `ffprobe input.webm`. You should see an output like this:

```
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 640x360, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
```

For converting a whole webm (VP8) to an animated webp use:

```bash
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx -i input.webm output.webp
```

For converting a whole webm (VP9) to an animated webp use:

```bash
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i input.webm output.webp
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to convert all the files to webmp in the folder? I tried `ffmpeg -i *.png *.webp` It doesn't work.

Comment: @c-an probably using the `find` command with the `-exec` option. You could take a look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/566200) or [this guide](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/calish-find.html).

Comment: @c-an See [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/)